# Dynamic Variable in Python While Loop

Tags: python, selenium

I got this python selenium while loop code.

1. If actual points less than or equal to 9 then do Tasks A
2. Else if actual points greater than 9 do Task B
3. Perform a While Loop until the actual points is greater than 9

**Here's my Code**

```
strpoints = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fs18").text
points = slice(13, len(strpoints)-20)
actualpoints = strpoints[points]

d = 0


while (d + actualpoints <9):
    # TASK A!!!
    print(actualpoints + ' Points! Skipping.')
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name('skip_button_single').click()

    time.sleep(8)

    if (d >= 10):
        break
# TASK B!!!
print(actualpoints + ' Points! Go for it!')
```

**Issue:**

The code above is not working properly because the variable `actualpoints` is dynamic.

IF actualpoints < 9 it will performed the assigned TASK B **BUT UNFORTUNATELY** it returns the same variable and it never changes.

Task A, reloads the page and displays a new number that should be stored in a variable called `actualpoints`.

**Other details related to my code and variables:**

- strpoints = getting the string that holds the number(s). Part of this string is static text and dynamic (numbers). Example: *You will get 12 points for following.*
- points = slicing the `strpoints`.
- actualpoints = the result after slicing the `strpoints`. Dynamic value.
- will perform a loop until > 10

any idea what's wrong with the code?

Comment: Can you share `strpoints` value example

Comment: Should the starting code here also be in the `while` loop e.g. `while True:`? Otherwise you never execute code that has a chance to modify `actualpoints`.

Comment: Updated the answer with example of strpoints

Answer (score 1):

In code below, `time.sleep` replaced with `wait` and `while` with `for` loop. Each iteration getting `strpoints` to use updated value. Regular expression used to extract `points` number from `strpoints`.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re

#...

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

for i in range(10):
    str_points = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "fs18"))).text
    print("str_points: " + str_points)
    points = re.search("\\d+", str_points)[0]

    if int(points) > 9:
        break

    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "skip_button_single"))).click()
    //time.sleep(8)

print(f'{points} Points! Go for it!')
```

Comment: i got this error: TypeError: string indices must be integers. I tried this: actualpoints = int(strpoints[points]) but still the same error.

Comment: @BenDaggers use `points = int(re.search("\\d+", strpoints)[0])`. check answer update.

Comment: It (sort of) worked but the variable points is not correct. the actual point i tested was 14 but it only captured 4. I think there's an issue if the actual point is 2 digits. I have updated question showing an example of the strpoints variable.

Comment: another issue/error, if the actual point is 1 digit (ex. 5), it returns an error of ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'i'

Comment: @BenDaggers try updated code and share print results

Comment: Here's the errors:

points: 4
actualpoints: w


    if i + actualpoints > 9:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: not sure why the print("actualpoints: " + actualpoints) returns a letter from the string.

Comment: actualpoints = the result after slicing the strpoints. Dynamic value and should be a number.

Comment: Remove `actualpoints`, no need. `points` already gives number

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190557/discussion-between-sers-and-ben-daggers).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will solve the problem, but maybe you can add an actualpoints validation method and variable to hold the last actualpoints value?

Here's your code and some of the additions I made.  I reworked your initial process into the while loop if I'm reading TASK A correctly, but feel free to modify this to suit your needs.

```
strpoints = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fs18").text
points = slice(13, len(strpoints)-20)
actualpoints = strpoints[points]

"""
    Create a temporary variable equal to the initial actualpoints value
"""
old_actualpoints = actualpoints

d = 0

def validate_actualpoints():
    """
        Simple value check query. Returns actual actualpoints value.
    """
    if old_actualpoints != actualpoints:
        old_actualpoints = actualpoints

    return actualpoints


while old_actualpoints == actualpoints:
    while (d + actualpoints < 9):
        # TASK A!!!
        print(actualpoints + ' Points! Skipping.')
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element_by_class_name('skip_button_single').click()

        """ Move the initial process into the while loop and re-run based on TASK A """
        strpoints = driver.find_element_by_class_name("fs18").text
        points = slice(13, len(strpoints)-20)
        actualpoints = strpoints[points]

        time.sleep(8)

        if (d >= 10):
            break

    """
    Update our temporary variable here?
    (Possibly not needed.)
    """
    old_actualpoints = validate_actualpoints()
    break
    # TASK B!!!
print(actualpoints + ' Points! Go for it!')
```